# Cassandra ignores updating null value spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cassandra

I am using spring boot `2.4.1` with `spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra`.

Here is the Repository class

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CassandraRepository<UserModel, String> {

}
```

Below is the POJO

```
@Table("user")
public class UserModel {

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "userid", type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private String userId;

    @Column("emailid")
    private String emailId;

    @Column("phonenumber")
    private String phoneNumber;

    //getters and setters
    }
```

Here is the class calling update method :

```
@Component
public class UpdateTask {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public void removePhoneNumber(UserModel t) {
        t.setPhoneNumber(null);
        userRepository.save(t);
    }

}
```

Problem is I want to update the phone number field to `null` as user wants to remove their phone number. But cassandra ignores the null value set. How to explicitly set a value to null in cassandra ?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score -2):

Try this one:

```
    public void removePhoneNumber(UserModel t) {
        UserModel userModelToUpdate = userRepository.getOne(t.userId);
        userModelToUpdate.setPhoneNumber(null);
        userRepository.save(userModelToUpdate);
    }
```

Comment: Why? What does this do differently? Why do you expect a different result?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, Is this working for you or not?

Comment: I'm not the OP. Code dumps with no explanations are not useful.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I will explain to you with the explanation but first, let me know this is working or not?

Answer (score -2):

It might be done with the DELETE cql command
-If an INSERT statement only specifies NULL values for a column or does not specify any values for a column, then the driver omits that column when executing the INSERT statement
you can refer to this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-3783